# What's the easiest non-memory intensive way to output XML from Python?

Tags: python, xml, streaming

Basically, something similar to System.Xml.XmlWriter - A streaming XML Writer that doesn't incur much of a memory overhead. So that rules out xml.dom and xml.dom.minidom. Suggestions?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

**xml.etree.cElementTree**, included in the default distribution of CPython since 2.5. Lightning fast for both reading and writing XML.

Comment: Still, cElementTree is not a streaming writer and thus will use memory linear to the size of the XML tree you create, although much less than xml.dom.

Answer (score 15):

I think you'll find XMLGenerator from xml.sax.saxutils is the closest thing to what you want.

```
import time
from xml.sax.saxutils import XMLGenerator
from xml.sax.xmlreader import AttributesNSImpl

LOG_LEVELS = ['DEBUG', 'WARNING', 'ERROR']


class xml_logger:
    def __init__(self, output, encoding):
        """
        Set up a logger object, which takes SAX events and outputs
        an XML log file
        """
        logger = XMLGenerator(output, encoding)
        logger.startDocument()
        attrs = AttributesNSImpl({}, {})
        logger.startElementNS((None, u'log'), u'log', attrs)
        self._logger = logger
        self._output = output
        self._encoding = encoding
        return

    def write_entry(self, level, msg):
        """
        Write a log entry to the logger
        level - the level of the entry
        msg   - the text of the entry.  Must be a Unicode object
        """
        #Note: in a real application, I would use ISO 8601 for the date
        #asctime used here for simplicity
        now = time.asctime(time.localtime())
        attr_vals = {
            (None, u'date'): now,
            (None, u'level'): LOG_LEVELS[level],
            }
        attr_qnames = {
            (None, u'date'): u'date',
            (None, u'level'): u'level',
            }
        attrs = AttributesNSImpl(attr_vals, attr_qnames)
        self._logger.startElementNS((None, u'entry'), u'entry', attrs)
        self._logger.characters(msg)
        self._logger.endElementNS((None, u'entry'), u'entry')
        return

    def close(self):
        """
        Clean up the logger object
        """
        self._logger.endElementNS((None, u'log'), u'log')
        self._logger.endDocument()
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Test it out
    import sys
    xl = xml_logger(sys.stdout, 'utf-8')
    xl.write_entry(2, u"Vanilla log entry")
    xl.close()
```

You'll probably want to look at the rest of the article I got that from at http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/03/12/py-xml.html.

Comment: +1: this is the only streaming answer here that's builtin to python.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have your poison :

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlite

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago I used `MarkupWriter` from [4suite](http://4suite.org/index.xhtml)

> ```
> General-purpose utility class for generating XML (may eventually be
> expanded to produce more output types)
>
> Sample usage:
>
> from Ft.Xml import MarkupWriter
> writer = MarkupWriter(indent=u"yes")
> writer.startDocument()
> writer.startElement(u'xsa')
> writer.startElement(u'vendor')
> #Element with simple text (#PCDATA) content
> writer.simpleElement(u'name', content=u'Centigrade systems')
> #Note writer.text(content) still works
> writer.simpleElement(u'email', content=u"info@centigrade.bogus")
> writer.endElement(u'vendor')
> #Element with an attribute
> writer.startElement(u'product', attributes={u'id': u"100\u00B0"})
> #Note writer.attribute(name, value, namespace=None) still works
> writer.simpleElement(u'name', content=u"100\u00B0 Server")
> #XML fragment
> writer.xmlFragment('<version>1.0</version><last-release>20030401</last-release>')
> #Empty element
> writer.simpleElement(u'changes')
> writer.endElement(u'product')
> writer.endElement(u'xsa')
> writer.endDocument()
>
> Note on the difference between 4Suite writers and printers
> Writer  - module that exposes a broad public API for building output
>           bit by bit
> Printer - module that simply takes a DOM and creates output from it
>           as a whole, within one API invokation
> ```

Recently i hear a lot about how [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) is great, but I don't have first-hand experience, and I had some fun working with [gnosis](http://freshmeat.net/projects/gnosisxml/).

Comment: I'm afraid 4suite is not online any more. As for lxml, it's great but does not have a styreaming facility AFAIK.

Answer (score -1):

I've always had good results with [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/). It's a pain to install, as it's mostly a wrapper around [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/), but `lxml.etree`  tree objects have a `.write()` method that takes a file-like object to stream to.

```
from lxml.etree import XML

tree = XML('<root><a><b/></a></root>')
tree.write(your_file_object)
```

Answer (score -2):

Second vote for ElementTree (cElementTree is a C implementation that is a little faster, like cPickle vs pickle).  There's some short example code here that you can look at to give you an idea of how it works: http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm
(this is Fredrik Lundh, who wrote the module in the first place.  It's so good it got drafted into the standard library with 2.5 :-) )