# Iteratively write XML nodes in python

Tags: python, xml, memory

There are many ways to read XML, both all-at-once (DOM) and one-bit-at-a-time (SAX). I have used SAX or lxml to iteratively read large XML files (e.g. wikipedia dump which is 6.5GB *compressed*).

However after doing some iterative processing (in python using ElementTree) of that XML file, I want to write out the (new) XML data to another file.

Are there any libraries to iteratively write out XML data? I *could* create the XML tree and then write it out, but that is not possible without oodles of ram. Is there anyway to write the XML tree to a file iteratively? One bit at a time?

I know I could generate the XML myself with `print "<%s>" % tag_name`, etc., but that seems a bit... *hacky*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the easiest non-memory intensive way to output XML from Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93710/whats-the-easiest-non-memory-intensive-way-to-output-xml-from-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fredrik Lundh's [elementtree.SimpleXMLWriter](http://svn.effbot.org/public/elementtree-1.3/elementtree/) will let you write out XML incrementally. Here's the demo code embedded in the module:

```
from elementtree.SimpleXMLWriter import XMLWriter
import sys

w = XMLWriter(sys.stdout)

html = w.start("html")

w.start("head")
w.element("title", "my document")
w.element("meta", name="generator", value="my application 1.0")
w.end()

w.start("body")
w.element("h1", "this is a heading")
w.element("p", "this is a paragraph")

w.start("p")
w.data("this is ")
w.element("b", "bold")
w.data(" and ")
w.element("i", "italic")
w.data(".")
w.end("p")

w.close(html)
```

Answer (score 1):

With lxml, you can use `etree.Element` to create new nodes, and `etree.tostring` to write out the XML representation. See, for example, [Listing 6. Serialize an element's children](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/#listing6) from [Liza Daly's article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/) "High-performance XML parsing in Python with lxml".

Comment: Do I need to have the whole tree in memory in order to use ``etree.tostring``? If so, this is a non-runner.

Comment: @Rory: The `fast_iter` function steps through the nodes without generating the entire DOM. You can then modify some or all of those nodes one-at-atime, and write them out with `etree.tostring`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're reading in XML dialect1, and have to write XML dialect2, wouldn't it be a good idea to write down the conversion process using **xslt**?  You may not even need any source code that way.

Comment: I don't mind about programming or not programming. The most important thing is the memory consumption. I do not have space to store all the source document in memory. Isn't XSLT memory intensive? (i.e. isn't that why STX was invented?)

Comment: @Rory: xslt allows you to specify the transformations in a declarative way.  Then you can _apply_ the transformation using the tools at hand.  I must admit I didn't have to bother about scalability yet.  I suggest you take a look at the available XSLT Processors.  A first look tells me that e.g. Saxon has a 'lazy construction' mode (http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/lib/FeatureKeys.html#LAZY_CONSTRUCTION_MODE)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find anything else, what I'd prefer here is to inherit from ElementTree and create a "iteractiveElementTree", adding to it a "file" attribute. I'd subclasse the nodes to have a "start_tag_comitted" attribute and a "commit" method. Upon being called, this "commit" method would call the render method for a subtree - starting from the fartest parent where e"start_tag_comitted" is false. With the string in hand I'd manually strip the closing tags for the parents of the current node. There is the need to handle the previously oppened but not closed parent siblings as well.

Then, I'd remove the  "commited" node from the memory model.
You will need to anotate node parents to each node as well, as ElementTree does not do that.

(Write me if there are no better answers an dyou get stuck there, I could implement this)