# MemoryError on generating large xml files using xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, json, xml, python-2.7, elementtree

I am reading from 120 `json` files of about 11MB each and converting them into single `xml` file.

I got a `MemoryError` halfway through processing into the 14th file.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import json

weightroot = ET.Element('meandata')  # root element
for x in range(60,7141,60):
    print "Processing weight for timestep:" + str(x)
    intervalTag = ET.SubElement(weightroot, 'interval', begin=str(x), end=str(x+60), id=str(x))  # 2nd element
    with open(str(x)+'.json') as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)
        for key, value in data.iteritems():
            ET.SubElement(intervalTag, 'edge', {'id': str(key), 'traveltime': str(value)})

weighttree = ET.ElementTree(weightroot)
newWeightFilePath = "weight_5.xml"
weighttree.write(newWeightFilePath)
```

Is there a more memory efficient way to process this? As you can see I am creating lots of SubElement tag that were not written to the actual `xml` file until the very end.

Comment: Try using `lxml` instead. It uses more memory-efficient C libraries.

Comment: After some searching about, it turns out that ElementTree has an iterative writer. There are other implementations out there too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377980/iteratively-write-xml-nodes-in-python.

Comment: I just tried lxml and it improved by just managing to process 2 more files.

Comment: Thats disappointing. I expected it to be better than that.

Comment: I used the iterative writer as suggested and it works flawlessly