# How to force indent of python LXML xml element nests when writing iteratively?

Tags: python, xml, iteration, lxml

I am using LXML to write an xml file that is a dump of a database.
Given the size of the data, I must write the xml file iteratively. When dumping the etree to a file, I run out of memory on a server with 32GB of ram.

I have written code that iteratively writes the xml via methods on this page https://lxml.de/api.html#incremental-xml-generation as referenced here [Iteratively write XML nodes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377980/iteratively-write-xml-nodes-in-python). The code is working well and my server is producing xml easily within the first 5gb of memory.

The only hitch is that the iterative write does not preserve the indentation that I had when dumping the etree.  I would like the indentation as in the picture below.

I have tried the etree.indent() method but it only indents 4 spaces within the client nests.  I have also tried hard coding spaces (like so xml_file.write("    ")) in a few places but then the individual tags become misplaced.

How can I force the "Client" nests to indent 4 spaces further than they are now?

Thank you very much for the help.

[image: Desired indentation]

[image: Existing indentation]

Code that generates the iterative xml writes and incorrect indentation:

```
from lxml import etree

client = etree.Element("Client")

client.append(etree.Element("ClientID"))
client[0].text = "12345"

client.append(etree.Element("ClientProfile"))
client[1].append(etree.Element("User"))

client[1][0].append(etree.Element("FirstName"))
client[1][0][0].text = "John"

client[1][0].append(etree.Element("LastName"))
client[1][0][1].text = "Doe"

client[1][0].append(etree.Element("AccountName"))
client[1][0][2].text = "Acme Inc"

client[1][0].append(etree.Element("EmailAddress"))
client[1][0][3].text = "user14@acmeinc.com"

client.append(etree.Element("SalesMetric"))
client[2].text = "12345"

filename = "test.xml"
with etree.xmlfile(filename, encoding="utf-8") as xml_file:
    with xml_file.element("DbDump"):
        xml_file.write("\n    ")

        version = etree.Element("ModelVersion")
        version.text = "1.2.1"
        xml_file.write(version, pretty_print=True)

        etree.indent(client, space="    ")

        for value in "12":
            xml_file.write(client, pretty_print=True)
```

Comment: Can you use an external XML formatter after writing it?

Comment: What does not work with [xml.etree.ElementTree.indent(tree, space='  ', level=0)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)?

Comment: @Barmar - This is a valid point and seems to be working with raw, un pretty printed xml files up to 2.5GB in a server with 32GB of ram and plenty of swap space. I may go for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
from lxml import etree
import copy

client = etree.Element("Client")

client.append(etree.Element("ClientID"))
client[0].text = "12345"

client.append(etree.Element("ClientProfile"))
client[1].append(etree.Element("User"))

client[1][0].append(etree.Element("FirstName"))
client[1][0][0].text = "John"

client[1][0].append(etree.Element("LastName"))
client[1][0][1].text = "Doe"

client[1][0].append(etree.Element("AccountName"))
client[1][0][2].text = "Acme Inc"

client[1][0].append(etree.Element("EmailAddress"))
client[1][0][3].text = "user14@acmeinc.com"

client.append(etree.Element("SalesMetric"))
client[2].text = "12345"

db_dump = etree.Element("DbDump")
version = etree.SubElement(db_dump, "ModelVersion")

db_dump.append(client)
client2 = copy.deepcopy(client)
db_dump.append(client2)
#etree.indent(db_dump, space="    ")
etree.dump(db_dump)

tree = etree.ElementTree(db_dump)
tree.write("output.xml", pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8")
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<DbDump>
  <ModelVersion/>
  <Client>
    <ClientID>12345</ClientID>
    <ClientProfile>
      <User>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Doe</LastName>
        <AccountName>Acme Inc</AccountName>
        <EmailAddress>user14@acmeinc.com</EmailAddress>
      </User>
    </ClientProfile>
    <SalesMetric>12345</SalesMetric>
  </Client>
  <Client>
    <ClientID>12345</ClientID>
    <ClientProfile>
      <User>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Doe</LastName>
        <AccountName>Acme Inc</AccountName>
        <EmailAddress>user14@acmeinc.com</EmailAddress>
      </User>
    </ClientProfile>
    <SalesMetric>12345</SalesMetric>
  </Client>
</DbDump>
```

Comment: Thank you! I never thought to copy and append the sub element to the root. For those needing 4 indent spaces vs 2, as shown in the answer, you can insert the following after etree.dump(db_dump). etree.indent(db_dump, space="    ") Put 4 spaces in the quotes.

Comment: @user3507825 The indent from lxml and pretty print is now correct, in tho opposite of the question. No need for 4 spaces anymore.

Comment: I inserted a comment, how you can ident(), if you really would change the standard of lxml.

Comment: I was given 4 spaces as a requirement, though I would rather have kept it at 2.

Comment: With this your question should be answered, please accept. Thanks.